# 20.04: Is it possible to lock the workspaces panel "out?"

Tags: workspaces, lock

I have a 27" x 2K monitor so plenty of viewing area. Is there some way I can lock the workspace panel in the out position?

Currently I have to

```
Tap the "Super"
Move the mouse to the right edge, about a 15"-travel, to pop it out.
Click the **twice** on workspace I want.
```

I know I can use the keyboard to move up/down, but sometimes I don't know which workspace I want to swap to.

Also, there seems to be no visual indication of which workspace I am in to know if I need to go up or down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When only a single workspace is in use, only the left part of the workspaces are shown on the right side of the Activities overview. This expands if two or more workspaces are in use.

You can change the behavior to always have these workspaces expanded using Gnome Shell extensions.  [Always Zoom Workspaces by jamien](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/503/always-zoom-workspaces/) is already older, but still works up to Gnome 3.38. The option to keep workspaces expanded also features as one of the many other settings in the extension  [Just Perfection by JustPerfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/), an extension that is very up to date and available for a range of Gnome Shell versions.

Comment: Thanks and FYI, the installations of 20.04 that I have, do not expand with 2 or more workspaces in use. I still have to tap the "Super" for it to peep out, then mouse over to have it expand. Then 2-more clicks before I can use it. Seems cumbersome to me. :)

Comment: Indeed, this behavior has sometimes changed between different Gnome Shell versions.

Comment: Ooops, I spoke too soon. Both of those slide it out to full width which saves 1-click later. But I want it locked out so it is visible all the time and not need the "Super" key to show it. Mint has the workspaces on the status bar visible all the time. Not going back to Mint just for that though. ;)

Comment: Workspaces to Dock did that, but is no longer maintained - it may or may not anymore work on Gnome 3.38. There are also extensions showing indicators on the top bar - take a look on the Gnome Extensions website and test them out.

Comment: Thanks again, I installed the Gnome Extensions yesterday and looked through, but could not find anything. One Extension shows the WS number on the top line, so at last II know where I am. Cliciking that number has a drop-down that shows all the Named WS. But I never know what's in what, so a fixed name for them doesn't help much. Still would like that WS-panel visible and fixed at all times. Thanks again for  the help.